# Bouncing arrow css - does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to do a mixture of three different things. A menu that appears half way down a screen after scrolling, a bouncing arrow and a side menu that opens once clicked.

This is an example page with all of these "attempts" are being made: http://www.new.techmoney360.com/youll-never-look-at-an-rpg-the-same-again/ 
(it is made in wordpress btw)

If you scroll half way down, you will see the menu appear on the left.

There are tons of issues with this I can see, but I will fix them as I go. Currently the one that is driving me nuts is a bouncing arrow.

This is what I am trying to replicate: https://codepen.io/dodozhang21/pen/siKtp

The arrow does not bounce, and I am not sure why? I got a new image for the arrow to the left, positioned it correctly and such. Can anyone give me some advice?

Here is the code for what I have done trying to implement this:

html:

```
<div id="sliderr" >
    <div class="arrow bounce">
    </div>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">Explore More</span>
</div>
```

css (regarding the bouncing arrow):

```
@import "compass/css3";

@include keyframes(bounce) {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        @include transform(translateY(0));
        }
        40% {
        @include transform(translateY(-30px));
        }
        60% {
        @include transform(translateY(-15px));
        }
}

.arrow {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left:-20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url("http://www.new.techmoney360.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/left-arrow-a.png");
    background-size: contain;
}

.bounce {
@include animation(bounce 2s infinite);
}
```

css with apearing menu:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px !important;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#sliderr {
    position:fixed;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 130px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin-left: -200px;
    z-index:9;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

Comment: I never use Sass so this might be a pretty dumb comment, but do you need the @include in here: \@include transform(translateY(0)); ?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your issue is that you are using the CSS from the example codepen link as is but you are not using the same kind of preprocessor for your CSS. Give this a try change your .bouncs and @keyframes css to the following:

```
.bounce {
  -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
}
```

If it works now then you are not using SASS or SCSS or any kind of CSS preprocessor. To see the css you need to use make sure to press the "View Compiled" button at the top right of the css window on codepen. It will spit out CSS you can use wihtout passing it through a compiler. Also note that this css includes vendor prefixes so it works cross browser.

Comment: That was the exact answer... 
Thank you so much. I was not aware about SASS but I did some searching and I now understand this.